# SQL How to find the most popular?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count, sql-order-by

Table 2

```
CourseNo | Store
1        | London
3        | Paris
4        | Tokyo
```

Table 1

```
ParticipantID | CourseNo
1             | 1
2             | 1
3             | 3
4             | 4
```

My question is how would I find out which store has the most participants when they are on separate tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can join, aggregate and limit:

```
select t2.store, count(*) no_participants
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.courseno = t1.courseno
group by t2.store
order by no_participants desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Sorry GMB I seem to be getting wrong results back I think. I currently have COURSENO  1 | STORE = LEEDS. COURSENO  2 | STORE = SHEFFIELD. COURSENO 3 | STORE = LEEDS. COURSENO 4 | COURSE = HULL then on the other table I have COURSENO 1 | PARTICIPANTID 2. COURSENO 1 | PARTICIPANT 3. COURSENO 3 | PARTICIPANTID 3 COURSENO 2 | PARTICIPANTID 1 and gives me back leeds=8 sheffield=4 hull=4 ? Sorry for the really bad layout